# My first schematic of a 2-channel relay board

Tags: relay, schematics, opto-isolator, esp8266, kicad

Hey all this would be my first try at creating a schematic in KiCad.

The schematic is a basic 2-channel relay.

The inputs are automotive 12v and gnd. This gets converted to 5v by the [K78L05-1000R3](https://www.mornsun-power.com/html/pdf/K78L05-1000R3.html).

The [Wemos D1 mini](https://escapequotes.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/d1-mini-esp8266-board-sh_fixled.jpg) has 2 digital pin outs that are 3.3v going to the [LTV-356T](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/lite-on-inc/ltv-356t/385804) with a [200 kOhms resistor](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/resistors/chip-resistor-surface-mount/200-kohms/52?s=N4IgjCBcoEwAwA4CsVQGMoDMCGAbAzgKYA0IAbgHZQAuATgK4kgD2UA2iPHAAQDWA8gAsAtvhABdUgAdqUEAFUKAS2r9MAWULZ89WoRABfI0A) in between.

From there it goes to a [1k resistor](https://www.yageo.com/upload/media/product/productsearch/datasheet/rchip/PYu-RC_Group_51_RoHS_L_12.pdf) and then to the [PMBT3904](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PMBT3904.pdf). Between that and the [G5LE-1 relay](https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-g5le.pdf) is a [1N4007F](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/1n4001-d.pdf).

In that same area is another 200 Ohms resistor that’s connected to an LED.

The outputs and inputs are the [2pos and 4pos 3.5mm Pitch Terminal Block Connector 300V 8A](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61qw-94giML._SL1500_.jpg).

Just want to make sure my values are good and the components I have selected are suitable for my application. Please let me know if I am missing anything or have a value incorrect. Thanks!

[image]

Question also asked on:
[maker.pro](https://maker.pro/forums/threads/my-first-schematic-of-a-2-channel-relay-board.299778/), [electronics-lab](https://www.electronics-lab.com/community/index.php?/topic/69198-my-first-schematic-of-a-2-channel-relay-board/), [allaboutcircuits](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/my-first-schematic-of-a-2-channel-relay-board.196334/), [kicad](https://forum.kicad.info/t/my-first-schematic-of-a-2-channel-relay-board/45253), [electro-tech-online](https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/my-first-schematic-of-a-2-channel-relay-board.165345/).

Comment: What do the opto's bring to the party?

Comment: as far as the schematic as technical *drawing* goes, and not the circuit it depicts: good idea to replace you very dominant 5V and GND lines simply by +5V and GND symbols, where appropriate. Always make 5V point up, and GND point down. And always have inputs on the left end of your schematic, and outputs on the right. If you have a transistor that connects something to ground, that transistor should be below that component.

Comment: @Andyaka It's said that its best to use a opto between a micro controller and whatever t is you are connecting the pin to in order to isolate it from said thing.

Comment: @StealthRT An opto is a good if you want to isolate, but your circuit does not isolate anything and the opto is just useless.

Comment: @Justme Thanks for the input. I think I will eliminate it from the design since you are correct - really not doing anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

- What do the opto's bring to the party? Meaning: there is no obvious reason for the circuit isolation that opto's bring.
- Power supply decoupling is an absolute must.
- Have you run a design rule check? KiCAD allows this and is necessary for any reasonable design i.e. find out what errors were produced.
- Have you linked the footprints for the parts? This is a sensible strategy for reducing errors when you convert to a PCB
- Have you checked the footprints for correctness? In other words, have you verified that the PCB footprints for the design are accurate to what the component data sheets tells you.
- Your LEDs on the relay circuits are, in effect, shorted out and won't do anything.
- Even if the shorts were removed, the LEDs are wired backwards.
- Unused pins on U1 need to be properly dealt with.
- I'd use a local 5 volt regulator from the 12 volts.
- Automotive jobs require extensive protection on the supply lines.

Comment: … and about decoupling, it's not only the bulk capacitors C3 and C4, but also necessary lower-ESR caps close to the microcontroller

Comment: … and unless you need galvanic isolation or have another good reason for relays: all your relays do is switch 12 V DC. Seeing there's probably unused output pins on the microcontroller, your whole circuitry might boil down to 1 microcontroller, 1 decoupling capacitor for that, 4 logic-level MOSFETs and 4 gate resistors, and possibly 4 pulldown/pullup resistors, depending on what you want default states to be.

Comment: @marcus I don't need any of the above so, I'd leave this comment under the question if I were you.

Comment: @Andyaka - Your answer is being flagged and one valid reason is that you are asking clarification questions to the OP in your answer. That is not correct site usage. Please either move your clarification questions out of the answer to a [comment](/help/privileges/comment) under the question, or rephrase them as statements. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - As mentioned above already, your comments appear to be answering the OP's question of whether they are "missing anything". Posting them as comments here is the wrong place.